# ArrayList inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My question is can I do the same thing with ArrayList which is asking the user to input name and price and access the object member and set the name and price or I must create the object first and pass it to the ArrayList?

```
public static void startMethod(Item[] itemsList, Scanner keyBoard){
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++) { // for loop iterate 3 times
        itemsList[i] = new Item(); // Create new object every time the loop iterate
        System.out.println("Enter an item's name");
        itemsList[i].setName(keyBoard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter an item's price");
        itemsList[i].setPrice(keyBoard.nextDouble());
        keyBoard.nextLine();// To avoid the skip line that is done by the nextLine() method
    }
```

or do I need to create the object first and pass the whole object? example

```
System.out.println("Enter a name");
    String input = key.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a price");
    double x = key.nextDouble();
    Item itemList1 = new Item(input,x);
    itemsList.add(itemList1);
```

Comment: Second one is preferable from performance perspective

Comment: 2nd  will be better solution

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: first one is *dangerous* , e.g. if user does not input complete or valid data, the list will contain an incomplete/invalid object. Also a bit less thread safe, during some time the list contains incomplete data. The `Item` can have `final` fields if using 2nd, preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second scenario is definitively better, more maintainable and probably easier to debug.

Moreover, most importantly, it will behave much better in the scenario when you encounter an exception when *constructing* your object - `Item`. The first scenario will require additional rollback mechanism since object is already present in the array.